# How to horizontal center a form using BootStrap?

Tags: html, forms, twitter-bootstrap

Hi there i am trying to position a login form in the middle of the screen using BootStrap 2. I  have tried several combinations using offset etc. But i do not seem to have anu luck..

```
<div class="row-fluid">
    <form action='' method='POST' id='loginForm' class='form-horizontal' autocomplete='off'>
    ...
    </form>
</div>
```

Any suggestions on how i can achieve this?

Comment: and what about classic way? did you try margin: 0 auto; or position:absolute;left:50%; ?

Answer (score 14):

if you want to use the grid system start by following @Pickle's answer.  This will center the spanned columns that contain your form.  If you want the form centered w/in that span, you'll have to do a bit more work such as the things mentioned by @kajo in his comment on your question.

To elaborate on @Pickle's answer, here's some sample code that centers a span of 4 columns in the default 12-column grid.  If you need a different number of columns spanned, use @Pickle's formula (but keep in mind your number of spanned columns must be an even number)

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="offset4 span4">
      .. form goes here ..
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 5):

Normally all spans are floated to left. So you have to float it to none and then set the margin to auto.

Something like this:

```
 <div class="span8" style="float:none; margin:0 auto"></div>
```

Comment: The only sensible answer. I made a css class called `center` and added `width: 100%` and now it works for everything including `form-horizontal` `dl-horizontal` `spanN` etc while remaining responsive. Brilliant!

Comment: The correct answer for this question!  It should be marked as so.

Answer (score 3):

Just set the classes so 2 * offsetClass + span class = 12 columns.

ie: `.offset4.span4`

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, currently the offset class doesn't work properly inside the row-fluid element.

https://github.com/twitter/bootstrap/pull/2394

If you want to use the row-fluid element, you can add a span4 with a br tag in it before your content div.

Answer (score 0):

After struggling so much with this center issue, I managed to create my own tweeks

CSS:

```
.control-group.center{ float:none;margin:0 auto;width:400px;margin-bottom:20px;}
.control-group .field {width:140px;float:left}
.control-group .l {width:120px;float:left;line-height: 29px;}
.row-fluid .offset4{
    display: block!important;
    float: none!important;
    width: 100%!important;
    margin-left: 0!important;
    padding:0 80px;
}
@media (max-width: 497px){
    .control-group.center {text-align: center;float:inherit;width: auto}
    .control-group .field,.control-group .l {width:120px;float:none;text-align: center;width: auto}
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
      <div class="row-fluid">
        <div class="offset4 span2">

          <form class="form-horizontal" action="enviar-pedido.php" method="post">
            <fieldset>
              <legend>Ingrese sus datos:</legend>
              <div class="control-group center">
                <div class="l">Nombre</div> <div class="field"><input type="text" id="txtNombre" name="txtNombre" placeholder="Nombre"></div>
              </div>
              <div class="control-group center">
                <div class="l">Email</div> <div class="field"><input type="text" id="txtEmail" name="txtEmail" placeholder="Email"></div>
              </div>
              <div class="control-group center">
                <div class="l">Teléfono</div> <div class="field"><input type="text" id="txtTelefono" name="txtTelefono" placeholder="Telefono"></div>
              </div>
            </fieldset>
          </form>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Now it is finally **forever** centered even when resizing the browser (Chrome and Firefox)